# android decrypt file using fingerprint

Tags: java, android

With the code below I can easily encrypt a file and decrypt it, using the password that the user enters. I am now imploding the use of the fingerprint to enter my app. When the fingerprint is correct, I want to decrypt the file. But how do I do if the user has not entered the password? is there a relatively safe way to do this? Thanks

```
public class CryptoUtils {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String ENCRYPTION_IV = "4e5Wa71fYoT7MFEX";
private static String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "";

public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
        throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
        throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
        throws CryptoException {
    try {

        ENCRYPTION_KEY = key;

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, makeKey(), makeIv());

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        //Log.d("cur__", "Encryption/Decryption Completed Succesfully");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CryptoUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static AlgorithmParameterSpec makeIv() {
    return new IvParameterSpec(ENCRYPTION_IV.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

private static Key makeKey() {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] key = md.digest(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        //Log.d("Lenghtis", new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM).getEncoded().length + "");
        return new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You first need to generate a Key. You can use the following function

```
fun generateKey(storeKey: StoreKey): SecretKey {

    val keyGenerator =
        KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "MyKeyStore")

    val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(storeKey.Alias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
        .build()

    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
    return keyGenerator.generateKey()
}
```

You need setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) for biometric authentication.

Then you can provide this key to your biometric authenticator to authenticate the user and in return you will receive cipher from it.

Then you can use that cipher (encrypt cipher OR decrypt cipher) to perform encrypt/decrypt data directly using this cipher.

```
androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01
```

like this

```
val biometricCallbacks = object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)

            result.cryptoObject?.cipher?.let { cipher ->
                val encryptedData = cipherUtils.encryptAES(dataToEncrypt, cipher)
                dismiss()
            }
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)

            if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_CANCELED || errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_USER_CANCELED) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed()
            Log.e("BIOMETRIC", "FAILED")
        }
    }

    val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, biometricExecutor, biometricCallbacks)

    val biometricPromptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("APP")
        .setSubtitle("Enable Biometric for Encryption")
        .setDescription("")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        .build()

    biometricPrompt.authenticate(
        biometricPromptInfo,
        BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(
            cipherUtils.getBioEncryptCipher(keyStoreUtils.generateNewKey(StoreKey.Pass, true))
        )
    )
```

You can encrypt users password and keep it securely in database somewhere and use the biometric authentication. Since the key you are generating is strictly bind to users biometrics, users encrypted password will not get compromised.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a concrete example in Java? I'm new to encryption and decryption and I want to make sure I do a good job. Also I wouldn't want to store the password anywhere. This will result in the non-recovery of the same, but as the documentation also says is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the androidx.biometric [demo app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/samples/BiometricDemos/src/main/java/com/example/android/biometric/BiometricPromptDemoBiometricBoundKeyActivity.java) for using **biometric-bound keys** (key can only be unlocked by strong biometric sensors).

Basically

1. Generate a key that's only usable after being authenticated via biometrics, with the associated capabilities you'd like the key to be able to perform (encrypt, decrypt, etc)
2. Wrap the cryptographic operation you wish to perform in a `CryptoObject`. The key will only become usable after a user has authenticated with biometrics
3. `Invoke BiometricPrompt#authenticate(CryptoObject)`
4. Use the key after `onAuthenticationSucceeded`

For completeness, there's also **authentication-bound keys** (key can be unlocked by biometrics *OR* device credential), which become available for use by your app whenever the user has authenticated within `t` seconds, where `t` is specified in `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds`. You can see an example usage [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/samples/BiometricDemos/src/main/java/com/example/android/biometric/BiometricPromptDemoCredentialBoundKeyActivity.java).